# Using a MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in which I am using a WHERE clause.

My QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE recipient= '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND viewed >  
'".$twoweeksago."' OR viewed IS NULL ORDER BY recieved DESC
```

Basically, the query selects all rows of data where the recipient is the user logged in and viewed is a date less than two weeks old ($twoweeksago is a variable set in my script). But, the default for the viewed column is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 so I had to use:

```
OR viewed IS NULL
```

This creates a problem. I thought it was a condition only applied to the previous condition, which is:

```
 AND viewed > '".$twoweeksago."'
```

But, it is actually an OR for the entire WHERE clause and voids all previous conditions. How can I write an OR condition that only affects AND viewed > '".$twoweeksago."'

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding parenthesis around `viewed > '".$twoweeksago."' OR viewed IS NULL`?

Comment: You can force conditions to be evaluated in the order you choose with parentheses - in this case `WHERE recipient... AND (viewed > ... OR viewed IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your conditions in a parenthesis like this:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE recipient= '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND (viewed > '".$twoweeksago."' OR viewed IS NULL) ORDER BY recieved DESC
```

This should work.

As a side note, you should remember to not use variables directly from the user, since it can introduce a security breech.

Answer (score 0):

You should add parenthesis around the grouped clause:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE recipient= '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND (viewed >  '".$twoweeksago."' OR viewed IS NULL) ORDER BY recieved DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE recipient= '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND (viewed IS NULL OR viewed > '".$twoweeksago."') ORDER BY recieved DESC
```

i believe that will work.

Comment: just like math or coding.. parenthesis are processed separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM notifications
WHERE recipient= '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'
AND (
    viewed > '" . $twoweeksago . "'
    OR viewed IS NULL
)
ORDER BY recieved DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE recipient= '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND (viewed >  
'".$twoweeksago."' OR viewed=NULL ORDER BY recieved DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
receipt = session
HAVING
viewed > time OR
viewed = null
ORDER BY
sort DESC
```

Using Pdo Your Example would look like this.

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'User', 'Pass');
$entry = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE receipt = :session HAVING viewed > :time OR viewed = null ORDER BY received DESC');
$entry->execute(array('session' => $Session, 'time' => $Time));
```

Makes it alot easier to Read, not to mention. Now you have more controll less ability to mess up. :3 PDO for the win anyone?